# Get Swagger JSON call body from Java Client

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I've generated a java client with `Swagger` using `swagger-codegen-cli` successfully.

I've many calls (get, put, etc) that work with no problem.
I'm now having an issue with a specific call, and for debugging I need to read the complete `JSON` generated by my calls, but I can't find it anywhere.

I've tried with debugger everywhere: the class `ApiClient` as an element `private JSON json;`, but I haven't found the full body in it neither.

Where can I find or extract that?

Thanks

Comment: In the past I used [TcpTunnelGui: maybe old but still useful](https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/tcptunnelgui-maybe-old-but-still-useful/) to check what's going on the wire. It is a simple proxy with GUI, you can see your request(s) and the server's response(s) on the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a try!

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are connecting to the server and returning the json object (such as with a print statement)?

Comment: @A.K. , what do you mean? Sorry I haven't understand

Comment: You say that you need to read the complete JSON generated by your calls. How is this JSON materializing? Is it the result of a get call or something else?

Comment: @A.K. yes, it's generated when I use my methods that swagger generator built for me. I simply call a method, that is converted into a web-service call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution: we need to intercept the `com.squareup.okhttp.Request` in the class `ApiClient` at the end of the `buildCall` method.

I've added in that method right before `return httpClient.newCall(request);` the call of my new method `printRequestBody(request);` which is the follow.

```
import okio.Buffer;
import okio.BufferedSink;

private void printRequestBody(Request request) {
    RequestBody requestBody;
    if(request.body() == null){
        System.out.println(request.tag().toString());
        return;
    }else{
        requestBody = request.body();
    }

    Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
    try {
        requestBody.writeTo(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(request.toString() + " --> "+buffer.readUtf8());

}
```

With this I've successfully got the print of my json body.